# Difference between "geben" and "schenken"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "geben" and "schenken"?
For example:

> Er **schenkt** keinem Mann Geld.

and

> Er **gibt** keinem Kind einen Apfel.

Both means "to give". Does it depend on the object?

Comment: The verb *schenken* does not mean *to give*, but *to give as a present*. Please throw away your current dictionary.

Comment: Also known as "to gift" ;)

Comment: Actually, @Janka, the English word "give" is really used in cases where we would say "schenken" in German. 
I remember trying to return a book to someone, to which he answered: "No, I gave it to you." "Nein, ich habe es dir geschenkt". So this is really a valid question.

Comment: It's the same in German. *Schenken* is just more explicit. That's why I wrote *throw away the dictionary* not making a difference between the two. Because that's the exact purpose of a dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The verb *geben* means: to give (anything).
The verb *schenken* means: to give **a present.**

*Schenken* also almost always means, that the owner of the given object is changing, which is not necessarily true for geben.

Examples:

> Der Lehrer **gibt** den Schülern eine Aufgabe.
>   The teacher **gives** the students a task.

The task is not a present, and the students do not become owner of the task. They just get it from the teacher.

> Martin **schenkt** seiner Frau einen Strauß Blumen.
>   Martin **gives** his wife a bouquet of flowers.

The flowers are a present. When Martin gave them to his wife they became a property of his wife.

> Der Blumenbinderlehrling **gab** seinem Chef einen Strauß Blumen.
>   The flower-arranger apprentice **gave** his boss a bouquet of flowers.

The apprentice is learning how to make a bouquet, and when he finished his work, he gave it to his boss, so that the boss could check, if the bouquet was ok. So in this case, the bouquet is not a present, and therefore you have to use a form of *geben* instead a form of *schenken*.